# How to align div inside page content in jQuery-Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a div inside jQuery-Mobile page div like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UFOcode/gtXzb/1/

```
<div data-role="page" data-pagination="1">
    <div data-role="content">
     <div class="iBorder">

     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to align class iBorder at left side and expand its size to screen frame.
I don't know why always have small gap on left and right

This is some trying CSS

```
.iBorder{
height: 300px;
width: auto;
margin: 0;
background-color: brown;    
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

and this is screen shot

[image]

Please help to to justify iBorder div and expand its size. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `.ui-content` is adding the extra padding, so there are two options.

#### Override jQuery UI CSS:

```
.ui-content {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

#### Change HTML markup, to avoid using .ui-content:

```
<div data-role="page" data-pagination="1">
     <div class="iBorder">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your user agent set default CSS, try to remove or override those defaults. In your case add this to your css:

```
body{
margin:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I just use one more jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css style. And this not work.

Answer (score 1):

As Unknown has pointed out, every browser has some default css. It's good practice to use this at the top of your css file to reset the default css;

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtXzb/3/) *(Using `!important` in the Fiddle, otherwise the jQuery Mobile CSS overrides the style)*

Comment: @UFO Did you use `!important`?

Comment: Yes, I also test both